# Returning and reporting on multiple return codes in SCCM package

Tags: sccm

I have a utility that detects pending restarts and prompts the user to restart. It also forces a restart on Sunday at 2AM if needed. I'd like to be able to report on who did what:

1. Ignored restart prompt (automatically goes away after 2 hours)
2. Clicked the "Later" button
3. Clicked the "Restart now" button
4. Computer Auto-restarted

I can send the different return codes from my Powershell script, but I don't know how I would setup the package to accept multiple return codes and report on it. I've found some documentation on MIF files, but it all seems to apply to older versions of SCCM - I'm running ConfigMgr 1910 and I'm good at SQL reporting, just need to get the data into a table somewhere.

Comment: I did only a quick search so maybe not 100% sure but it confirmed what I already assumed which is it is not really feasible for packages. There is no way to define additional exit codes, the only way would be some site wide file manipulation which is not worth it imo. The good news is this should be possible with an application instead. There you can define different return codes as success. Is this an option? The other way would be to just let the package be detect as failed. Then you can return what you want. You can however never use the "rerun if failed" option anymore and it's a bit hacky

Comment: The package is set to Always Re-run, so that's not a problem, but SCOM is going to be alerting on managed systems about all the "failures". Even with an application, can I report on the return code or does it just come back as "success"?

Comment: The main difference should just be that you can declare a non zero return code as success. Reporting on the return code should not be a problem as all the default reports about program status should already include the return code anyways. I don't know the table by heart but I will take a look tomorrow

Comment: I looked into this a little deeper and it seems they really only report the error return codes not the success ones for applications which is very unfortunate. So it seems you either would have to use programs and let them fail or you have to go the long route with writing your status to the registry and adding the values to HW inventory but this is ofc not as fast. Depending on your settings you could have quite the delay until your report has all the latest data. Final possibility is using your own db for your status and joining the data in the report but this is all not very elegant, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this git project can help you to send the information via custom status messages:
https://github.com/MattiasC85/Send-CMMessage